# htaccess 301 redirect of matching string to another domain url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Am trying to redirect url of domain a to domain b, wherein redirection is done to fit in to best possible url of domain b

For ex, domain A from which 301 redirect to be done    .

```
http://www.abc.com/blog/
http://www.abc.com/old-games?view=pages&layout=sell
```

There are many pgaes next to blog and many pages as sub url under old-games etc.

Domain B

```
http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_blog&view=entry&Itemid=5
http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=sellgames&Itemid=10
```

Have tried below htaccess redirect conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/blog.*$
RewriteRule .*   http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_blog&view=entry&Itemid=5 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/old-games.*$
RewriteRule .*  http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=sellgames&Itemid=10 [R=301,L]
```

The redirect is happening to

```
 http://www.xyz.com/index.php as tested using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
```

Pl suggest for best way as if missin something in above

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/|$) http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_blog&view=entry&Itemid=5 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^old-games(/|$) http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=sellgames&Itemid=10 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure to test in a different browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: Much thanks, but was there a problem in my code which i wrote above. thnx

Comment: You're welcome, yes problem in your code was mainly related to regex you had used.